# Wordpress - вывод нескольких одинаковых ссылок

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте.

Я хочу на своем сайте, в футере выводить текст с ссылками например:

моды для **А**, текстуры для **А**, дополнения для **А**

где **А** это:

```
<a href="<?php $cat = get_the_category();echo get_category_link($cat[0]->cat_ID); ?>" title="" class="child" ><? echo $cat[0]->cat_name; ?></a>
```

Так вот, т.к. это **А** придется вывести 4-5 раз - хочу спросить:

Сильно ли это повлияет на быстродействие?

Может лучше как то записать это в function.php и вызывать от туда?

Подскажите решение.

Спасибо.

Comment: **Я хочу на своем сайте, в футере выводить текст с ссылками например:...**
Не совсем корректный вопрос на мой взгляд.
 - сколько ссылок (нужна ли база данных) работа с базой "длительный" процесс, может лучше использовать массив.
 - как выводятся ссылки, последовательно или случайно?

Comment: Я же написал как будет выглядеть текст, вместо А подставляется категория в которой находится человек. т.е. "А" будет равно категории  в которой находимся, и мне надо вставить ссылку на эту категорию с анкором ввиде названии категории.
Конечно выводить рандомный анкор и ссылки это было бы лучше - но это по моему слишком геморно, я не решился просить такое сделать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Адекватным решением в общем случае (не только для вордпресса) будет вынос повторяющихся вызовов:

```
<?php 
$cat = get_the_category();
$a = '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat[0]->cat_ID).'" title="" class="child" >'.$cat[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
?>
моды для <?=$a?>, текстуры для <?=$a?>, дополнения для <?=$a?>
```

Если в `get_the_category` и `get_category_link` происходят запросы к БД, это идеальное решение.

Answer (score 0):

`$box = array( 
     '0'   => '<a href="www.site1.ru" title="" 
                  class="child"> название1 </a>', 
     '1'  => '<a href="www.site2.ru" title="" 
                  class="child" > название2 </a>', 
     '2' => '<a href="www.site2.ru" title="" 
                 class="child" > название2 </a>', 
         );

/**
* Выбор случайного значения из массива 
* Choice of casual value from a file
*/`

$cat = $box[rand(1,count($box))];